# Delete all directories that contain digit(s) except for the most recently created in Red Hat Linux Server using Regex

Tags: regex, linux, jenkins, redhat

File Structure:

```
/56
/57
/58
/lastFailedBuild
/lastStableBuild
...
```

I'm trying to delete only `/56` and `/57`.

Here is my current shell script that gets run during my Jenkins process.

```
rm -rf [0-9]*
```

but that obviously also deletes `/58`. I would like to do something like this: `rm -rf [0-9]*!({env.BUILD_NUMBER})` where I'm able to keep the rest of the directories including `/58`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get a list of directories without the last one using `head -n -1`:

```
rm -rf `ls -d [0-9]* | head -n -1`
```

On the platforms where `head -n -1` is not available, `sed '$ d'` may be used instead (credits to @l'L'l):

```
rm -rf `ls -d [0-9]* | sed '$ d'`
```

Comment: This is a viable solution, although `head -n -1` might not work on some distros. Perhaps you could include `| sed '$ d' ` as an alternative. If you add it to your answer I'll delete mine and upvote this one. :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! when I run this on the jenkins, it deletes the files inside the most recently created directory (for example /58/log) which I need. Can you give me a pointer ? thanks

Comment: @RayKim, not sure why this happens. I'd try to check `ls -d [0-9]* | head -n -1` first and see if it returns exactly the list of directories intended for removal. If that fails, examine `ls -d [0-9]*` output in detail.

Comment: *On the platforms where `head -n` is not available..."* - `head -n` is Posix and it should be available everywhere. Also see [`head` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/head.html).

Comment: @jww: `head -n` will work, although `head -n -1` sometimes will not. On distros that it doesn't `head: illegal line count -- -1` will be returned instead.